# Paypal payment pro error

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I am using magento shopping cart version 1.7.0.0

Paypal express checkout working fine with my store

but paypal pro gives below error

PayPal gateway has rejected request. This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration (#10501: Invalid Configuration).

In my paypal business account

```
Services            Status
PayPal Payments Pro Live
Virtual Terminal    Live
Fraud Management    Live
PayPal Express Checkout Live
```

I have google for this problem and it tells that

This error occurs due to the billing agreement is disabled or inactive.

How to check paypal payment pro is enabled or not.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow this thread: [Paypal Website Payments Pro (US) + Sandbox + Magento 1.4.0.1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/177550/#t225636)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you haven't signed up for PayPal Website Payments Pro.
If you're in the US, UK or Canada you can call PayPal and ask to be signed up for 'Website Payments Pro'.

Note: PayPal has rebranded a few of their products, and they may offer you 'PayPal Payments Pro' instead. In order to resolve the error you're seeing, you *must* have Website Payments Pro.